# xcode : retrieving one line of xcode based on search query

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, search, csv

Here is a sample of my CSV

```
10820   0   0   0   0
10900   2   4   4   4
11000   21  50  54  58
11100   23  54  59  63
11200   25  59  63  68
11300   27  63  68  73
11400   29  68  73  78
11500   31  72  78  83
11600   32  76  82  88
11700   34  81  87  93
```

I'm looking to create to use xcode to retreive one line of code from this very lengthy CSV based on the first line.

For example:

1. if the user enters "10900", the second line columns will be returned.
2. If the user returns 11650, the 11600 line columns will be returned...always taking the lower line when the input value is less then the following line.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've seen code to parse an entire CSV file, but I'm thinking this may be a big memory drain, right now my CSV has 2000 lines of values, which are all in ascending order based on the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load a file into memory anyways to find correct value.

With such a big CSV file I would recommend to turn CSV file into binary file (plist file for example) and put it as binary into your application - instead of parsing it each time in RunTime. It has much better performance and it's easier to work with that since you are working directly with NSDictonaries an NSArrays.

If you don't want to do it for some reason, the next solution is to use something like CHCSVParser:
https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

It provides optimization for loading only part of file at a time - which is the optimization you might be looking for.